# Prove that the sum is bounded on $[-1,1]$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem.

> (a) Prove that the series $\sum \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$ is convergent for
>   all $x\in \mathbb R$. We denote $R(x)$ its sum.
>
> (b) Prove that $R$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$.

I have proven the first problem a, but I have no idea how to prove b.

Every hint, suggestion or solution is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Try using ratio test

Comment: The implication from a to b is almost trivial: any power series is uniformly convergent on the interior of its converence interval, hence continuous on it. Hence the boundedness since $[a,b]$ is compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{x} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.
$$
To compute $\sum_{n} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ you should tell us the first value of the index $n$ you're taking into account. Anyway, you should compare it to
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$

Comment: Is it not possible to evaluate the sum? What does it equal to?

Answer (score 2):

Convergent for all $x\in\Bbb R\implies$ series uniformly convergent in any bounded interval $\implies$ $R$ continuous.

Answer (score 1):

for $x \in [-1,1]$, $|x| \leq 1$. This implies that $|x^n| \leq 1$. Then we have that:

$$\left||\sum \frac{x^n}{n!} \right| \leq \sum \left| \frac{x^n}{n!} \right|$$

by the triangle inequality. Further:

$$\sum\left| \frac{x^n}{n!} \right|=\sum \frac{|x^n|}{n!} \leq \sum \frac{1}{n!}$$

this looks suspiciously like the taylor expansion for $e^x$, evaluated at $0$...

alternatively, for all $n \geq 2$, we know that $n! \geq n^2$...